# Android pass Uppercase first character of API with retrofit

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit2

in our webservice we can pass username and password with this below structure and we can get data from server successful

```
POST  ->  http://www.sample.com/Service1.svc/login

Content-Type: application/json

Body: 

{
"UserName": "1",
"Password": "1"
}
```

or with Curl:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i 'http://www.sample.com/Service1.svc/login' --data '{
"UserName": "1",
"Password": "1"
}'
```

my problem with `Retrofit` is Uppercase of first characters on username and password when i implementing this below code i get `0` as username and password is not correct

`LoginSchema` class:

```
class LoginSchema {
    private int Username;
    private int Password;

    public LoginSchema(int username, int password) {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }
}
```

`Retrofit` implementation:

```
LoginSchema loginSchema = new LoginSchema(1, 1);

Call<Integer> call = requestService.checkLoginAccount(loginSchema);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Integer>() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<Integer> call, @NotNull final Response<Integer> response) {
        try {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventLoginResult(true, response.body().toString()));
            } else {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventLoginResult(false, null));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventLoginResult(false, null));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Integer> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

and then API implementation:

```
public interface RestfulWebServices {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/Service1.svc/login")
    Call<Integer> checkLoginAccount(@Body TaskLogin.LoginSchema loginSchema);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your POJO class should be like below.

```
class LoginSchema {
    @SerializedName("UserName")
    private int Username;
    @SerializedName("Password")
    private int Password;

    public LoginSchema(int username, int password) {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }
}
```